# How do I make my pen anchor points around isometric grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

As you can see in the photo there lines dont link up pefectly and don't follow the guidelines precisely. Is there a way I can make every exact?

Comment: Hi TomMlo, to get a better answer to your question you should add the tag of the application you are using.

Comment: Have you tried enabling "Snap to Point", assuming you are using Adobe Illustrator, which you forgot to mention.

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. I am using Illustrator. I have enabled Snap to Point, however, I'm only really able to connect these points if i'm zoomed in a lot. Do I need to hold down any key as well?

Comment: Dont make the grid out of lines make it out of segments

Comment: Click off **Align to pixel grid** from the **Transform Panel**

Comment: @Danielillo Snap to pixel must be the worst add on to the software ever ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually user joojaa has already shown in short form what to do. You need an anchor point in every crossing of the grid lines. Insert them, it takes only few seconds.

- have a grid made of long lines, do not lock it
- select all
- goto the pathfinder panel and select Outline
- select all, restore the wanted stroke color and width (everything loses its color and width with outline)
- lock your grid to keep it in place (It's a group automatically, ungrouping it accidentally causes easily a serious trouble)

Now snap to points work much more easily, you do not need to stare if there reads intersection.

Increase the snap to points distance in the preferences, if needed.